# Open a window containing a form in a firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I need open a window to give some data to the addon like a URL to visit and other data. When these data is entered successfully user clicks a [GO] button and open a new tab where load this URL and so on.
So I already have a button in the addon bar to trigger this window open action. But how can I open this window and how can I load the needed form to receive these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a prompt to display the form input and open the window using the [openUILinkIn](http://xulfr.org/wiki/RessourcesLibs/Firefox) function. Pass the input as the first argument, and "tab" as the second argument:

```
var url = window.prompt("Enter the URL");
openUILinkIn(url, "tab");
//window.open(url);
```

Comment: Enter an URL is just an example of data to be asked. I asked for a ` form` not just a textbox-like input. But this questions is quite old and your answer is useful so accept it as good. Thanks!